# update column having double space to have a comma

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a table which have columns and they have data as comma separated

i used replace to replace that comma with space and updated the table, now due to some incompatibility i had to revert the change and i missed to take backup

so my columns which were replaced have spaces like this

```
The S.T.A.B.L.E.Manual  6th Ed
```

see the space between `Manual` and `6th`

i want it should go back to this

```
The S.T.A.B.L.E. Manual, 6th Ed
```

Comment: Although it might lead to undesired results if there are double spaces where there shouldn't be, couldn't you just replace double spaces with ', '?

Comment: How did a space appear before "Manual"?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should be careful, but you can do:

```
update t
    set col = replace(col, '  ', ', ')
    where col like '%  %';
```

This does not handle the space before "Manual".  That is not in your description of the problem.

Comment: isn't it should be `update t
    set col = replace(col, '  ', ', ')
    where col like '%  %';`